# How do I detect a swiping / flicking gesture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to allow the user to flick a ball that is on screen.  The user would tap on the ball and then flick, the velocity / speed of the flick would then dictate initial velocity.

I took a look at [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer) but it seems like that is more targeted at navigation than flicking.

How do I go about implementing this?

I am using Cocos2d and Box2d.

Comment: Take a look at [UIResponders](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Getting the touch point requires a UIView though, how do I get one from CCLayer (my base class)     gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:];

Comment: - edited out stupid question >:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered UIPanGestureRecognizer? You can get velocity data from that ([panGesture velocityInView:]), and distinguish the initial velocity of the 'swipe' using the state property on the gesture recognizer.

Or is that not sufficient?

Comment: Hey Ben, this sounds promising, do you have any code that I could look at? Cheers

Comment: The [iOS reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is very good. It shows the properties and the methods you can use on the class:. I would have posted code, but you can't do that in comments.